# Elasticsearch Exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying a search in ElasticSearch but it is giving an error :

```
[failed to parse search source[{
    "sort": {
        "sorter": {
            "order": "desc",
            "mode": "max"
        }
    },
    "query": [{
        "match": {
            "muteFeedUserIds": "56f4ca2f44fc8650411170b0"
        }
    }, {
        "match": {
            "approvalStatus": "approved"
        }
    }],
    "filter": {
        "range": {
            "sorter": {
                "to": "2016-06-28",
                "include_upper": false
            }
        }
    }
}]];
nested: ElasticsearchParseException[failed to parse search source.expected field name but got[START_OBJECT]];
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this query instead:

```
{
  "sort": {
    "sorter": {
      "order": "desc",
      "mode": "max"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "muteFeedUserIds": "56f4ca2f44fc8650411170b0"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "approvalStatus": "approved"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "sorter": {
            "to": "2016-06-28",
            "include_upper": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try following approach (it is also faster way, rather using filter):

```
 {
  "sort": {
    "sorter": {
      "order": "desc",
      "mode": "max"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "muteFeedUserIds": "56f4ca2f44fc8650411170b0"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
           "approvalStatus": "approved"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "sorter": {
              "from": "2015-06-28",
              "include_upper": false
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": []
    }
  }
}
```

This should definitely fix your error.